# How to pick every player in a range/region?

Tags: lua, coregames

I think I already saw it in the CoreGames tutorials but I forget it, can you tell me pls?
[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96sEu.png)

Comment: being new is not an excuse. when you post a question you're provided with plenty of information about what is expected in this community and how to ask a well received question.

Comment: In fact being new means I'm not yet familiarized of what you reffer with "a good question" even if you gave me indications, because I read the indications that the site gave me before asking, also for being new if you gave me a more detailed tips to make a question, I'm not very motivated to take them **yet** even I read it completly.

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm not justifying me, I just explained why I did what I did, in other context I wouldn't say anything and just "take what I deserve", but I consider a little unfair the punishment of can't ask for 3 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could've just Googled `coregames find players in region` or something similar and take a look. I immediately spotted [Game.FindPlayersInSphere](https://docs.coregames.com/api/game/#findplayersinsphere) which you could use.

Otherwise simply iterate through the players and check whether their position (the X/Y/Z components) fit within a box you specify, in case a sphere doesn't fit your needs.

Comment: I searched it in the Core API and it didn't apeared, but yes, I could search it in Google better, thank you.

Comment: Being in software development means you often have to be good at Googling APIs (or bugs, ...) and figuring out how to use the available API to reach your goal.